# Full calender - Remove Events on day click and remove Bg-color of particular cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to limit the events to one in a particular date, and on click of date if any events are present, it has to be removed.

While adding an event to a date, the color of the cell should be turned orange, and while deleting the event, it has to be turned back to white.

$(function  ()  {

```
        // Full calendar
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            backgroundColor: 'orange',
                            allDay: allDay,                             
                        },
                        true
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            eventClick: function(event){
                var r=confirm(\"Are you sure?\");
                if (r==true)
                  {
                     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
                  }                                                          
            },
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    if($( this ).hasClass('bg-orange')){
                   $(this).removeClass('bg-orange');
               }
               else
               {
                $(this).addClass('bg-orange');
               }                      
            },              
            editable: true,
            events: [
            ]
        });
    });
```